# Find specific data from command output using awk in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to read the specific data from the output of the command using awk,
From here , http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/

I have learned how to read data from a text file, but i do not want to read the data from text file,
I instead want to read the data from the output of this command,

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 4800 && cat < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The output of the command is as follows,

```
$GPGGA,152826.996,2452.8328,N,06701.2544,E,1,03,3.2,32.7,M,-46.4,M,,0000*48

$GPGSA,A,2,16,23,32,,,,,,,,,,4.5,3.2,3.2*35

$GPRMC,152826.996,A,2452.8328,N,06701.2544,E,2.03,112.95,261213,,,A*6F

$GPGGA,152827.995,2452.8282,N,06701.2520,E,1,03,3.2,32.7,M,-46.4,M,,0000*49

$GPGSA,A,2,16,23,32,,,,,,,,,,4.5,3.2,3.2*35

$GPRMC,152827.995,A,2452.8282,N,06701.2520,E,0.45,148.25,261213,,,A*6A
```

I wanted to read the `3rd` and `5th` value of the line that matches with `GGA` from the above output
so I have used this,

```
awk -F"," '/GGA/ {print $3,$5}'
```

here , `-F defines a field separator, i.e. ','`

and my Final command is,

```
awk -F"," '/GGA/ {print $3,$5}' stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 4800 && cat < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

but the command outputs nothing and gives the following error,

> awk: cannot open stty (No such file or directory)

So I tried

```
awk -F"," '/GGA/ {print $3,$5}' | stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 4800 && cat < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I don't know where I have read this but i know it has to do something with `|`, which is why i tried the above command, but still nothing happens, and this time i have to terminate the Output using `CTRL+C`

How can I output only 3rd and 5th values of the lines that matches GGA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your pipe (`|`) chaining the other way around:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 4800 && cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 | awk -F"," '/GGA/ {print $3,$5}'
```

so that the output of `cat < /dev/ttyUSB0` is fed into your `awk` command,

Note that you should remove the call to the  `cat` command:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 4800 && awk -F"," '/GGA/ {print $3,$5}' < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: fantastic , thanks a lot. :)
P.S: is there anyway to name the two variables $3 and $5 with something else. for instance, the above command would output, 
2452.8255 06701.2333
is it possible to make the output looks like this ->

Long: 2452.8255 Lat: 06701.2333

Comment: You can write whatever you want in the `awk` script to print: rather than `'/GGA/ {print $3,$5}'`, write `'/GGA/ {print "Long:",$3,"Lat:",$5}'`

Comment: does it possible to write the output of above command into a file now ? the output is infinite so how could i write it into a file ?
i have tried this but just empty file is creater, stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ispeed 4800 && awk -F"," '/GGA/ {print $3,$5}' < /dev/ttyUSB0 > output.txt

Comment: You then need to force the write to the file with `fflush()` : `{ print "Long:",$3,"Lat:",$5 ; fflush(stdout) }` . Otherwise, `awk` will buffer the output.